# Pass a variable from jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I added functions in `function.php` and I should pass form a jQuery to PHP variable; I tried to use an ajax post but I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: call to undefined function add_action()

and the variable doesn't change. I know that in wordpress I need to use a different syntax for ajax calls but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$prezzo = $_POST['espressione'];

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'totale', 31 );

/**
* ------
*/


?>
<script>
function espressione()
{
    totale = ((android*prezzo_android)+(manager*prezzo_manager)+gruppi);

    if (!(totale < 0))
    {
        $('#product_total_price .price').html( '€' + totale.toFixed(2));

        jQuery.ajax(
            {
                url:'/funzioni/function.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {espressione: totale},
                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(response)
                }
            })
    }
    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(totale <= 0));

}

/**
* ------
*/

<?php
echo $prezzo;
?>
```

Comment: Here you are able to pass parameter from jquery to php, the problem is in php file, Where is `add_action()` function assigned, have you created this?

Comment: yes, I created add_action in the php file, it must have been all the others, that is function.php

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request, you need to specify the name of the php function, like so:

```
data: {'espressione': totale, 'action': 'myFunction'},
```

And in PHP, you need to use `wp_ajax_pay` and `wp_ajax_nopriv` actions, like so:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```

And then run the function:

```
function myFunction(){
    $prezzo = $_POST['espressione'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: error: uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined, I copied and inserted everything as you said

Comment: @Gulands did you post php code in functions.php file?

Comment: yes, all the other functions work, but from that error on the call

Comment: @Gulands I made some ajustment on the first line of code. Did you try?

Comment: now it works but always the same error as before:"Uncaught Error: call to undefined function add_action()"
I have also added the two actions: wp_ajax_myFunction, wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: i used trusted theme